# JQuery/Javascript - Search DOM for text and insert HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, insert

How do I search the DOM for a certain string in the document's text (say, "cheese") then insert some HTML immediately after that string (say, "< b >is fantastic< /b >").

I have tried the following:

```
for (var tag in document.innerHTML) {
    if (tag.matches(/cheese/) != undefined) {
        document.innerHTML.append(<b>is fantastic</b>
    }
}
```

(The above is more of an illustration of what I have tried, not the actual code. I expect the syntax is horribly wrong so please excuse any errors, they are not the problem).

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are native methods for finding text inside a document:

MSIE:[textRange.findText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
Others: [window.find()](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php)

Manipulate the given textRange if something was found.
Those methods should provide much more performance than the traversing of the whole document.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>

  <script>
  function fx(a,b)
  {
    if(window.find)
    {
      while(window.find(a))
      {
        var node=document.createElement('b');
            node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b));
        var rng=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            rng.collapse(false);
            rng.insertNode(node);
      }
    }
    else if(document.body.createTextRange)
    {
      var rng=document.body.createTextRange();
      while(rng.findText(a))
      {
        rng.collapse(false);
        rng.pasteHTML('<b>'+b+'</b>');
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="fx('cheese','is wonderful')">
<p>I've made a wonderful cheesecake with some <i>cheese</i> from my <u>chees</u>e-factory!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrapping the text once you've found it is non-trivial in non-IE browsers.

Comment: The question is about appending not surrounding, that's trivial in non-IE-browsers too.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not convinced this will be as precise as the DOM traversal solution in terms of exactly where it puts these nodes that are being created, there's a case sensitivity issue to address and it messes with the user's selection, but it does work and is a valid alternative. +1.

Comment: Both methods have parameters to set case-sensitivity, it's just a simple example not a finished solution.

Comment: I stumbled on a similar problem and found your solution very helpful. Do you know how I could wrap the found text in a `<b>` tag, for example? I have done this in Firefox, but I'm stuck with IE8.

Comment: The code above wraps the text in a   `<b/>` and should work in IE8

Answer (score 6):

This is crude and not the way to do it, but;

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/cheese/, 'cheese <b>is fantastic</b>');
```

Comment: Hopefully "cheese" will not inside of element-attributes, CSS or JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this with JQuery:

```
$('*:contains("cheese")').each(function (idx, elem) {
    var changed = $(elem).html().replace('cheese', 'cheese <b>is fantastic</b>');
    $(elem).html(changed);
});
```

I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should work.

Note that `*` will match all elements, even `html`, so you may want to use `body *:contains(...)` instead to make sure only elements that are descendants of the document body are looked at.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Solution:**

```
<ul>
  <li>cheese</li>
  <li>cheese</li>
  <li>cheese</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery codes:**

```
$('ul li').each(function(index) {
  if($(this).text()=="cheese")
  {
    $(this).text('cheese is fantastic');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to traverse the document and search each text node for the desired text. Any way involving `innerHTML` is hopelessly flawed.

Here's a function that works in all browsers and recursively traverses the DOM within the specified node and replaces occurrences of a piece of text with nodes copied from the supplied template node `replacementNodeTemplate`:

```
function replaceText(node, text, replacementNodeTemplate) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        while (node) {
            var textIndex = node.data.indexOf(text), currentNode = node;
            if (textIndex == -1) {
                node = null;
            } else {
                // Split the text node after the text
                var splitIndex = textIndex + text.length;
                var replacementNode = replacementNodeTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                if (splitIndex < node.length) {
                    node = node.splitText(textIndex + text.length);
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, node);
                } else {
                    node.parentNode.appendChild(replacementNode);
                    node = null;
                }
                currentNode.deleteData(textIndex, text.length);
            }
        }
    } else {
        var child = node.firstChild, nextChild;
        while (child) {
            nextChild = child.nextSibling;
            replaceText(child, text, replacementNodeTemplate);
            child = nextChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example use:

```
replaceText(document.body, "cheese", document.createTextNode("CHEESE IS GREAT"));
```

If you prefer, you can create a wrapper function to allow you to specify the replacement content as a string of HTML instead:

```
function replaceTextWithHtml(node, text, html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var templateNode = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (div.firstChild) {
        templateNode.appendChild(div.firstChild);
    }
    replaceText(node, text, templateNode);
}
```

Example:

```
replaceTextWithHtml(document.body, "cheese", "cheese <b>is fantastic</b>");
```

I've incorporated this into a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/azZsa/

Answer (score 0):

Works in all browsers except IE I think, need confirmation though.

This supports content in iframes as well.

Note, other examples I have seen, like the one above, are RECURSIVE which is potentially bad in javascript which can end in stack overflows, especially in a browser client which has limited memory for such things. Too much recursion can cause javascript to stop executing.

If you don't believe me, try the examples [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=zakas%20recursion%20javascript&source=bl&ots=2Uni-H1gjN&sig=V7a-odOtCt2Hptq_ZC1lQD4x-G4&hl=en&ei=Tx_oTcnlEordiALj-rmEAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) yourself...

If anyone would like to contribute, the code is [here](https://github.com/mawkor2/grepNodes).

```
function grepNodes(searchText, frameId) {
  var matchedNodes = [];
  var regXSearch;
  if (typeof searchText === "string") {
    regXSearch = new RegExp(searchText, "g");
  }
  else {
    regXSearch = searchText;
  } 
  var currentNode = null, matches = null;
  if (frameId && !window.frames[frameId]) {
    return null;
  }
  var theDoc = (frameId) ? window.frames[frameId].contentDocument : document;
  var allNodes = (theDoc.all) ? theDoc.all : theDoc.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var nodeIdx in allNodes) {
    currentNode = allNodes[nodeIdx];
    if (!currentNode.nodeName || currentNode.nodeName === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    if (!(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase().match(/html|script|head|meta|link|object/))) {
      matches = currentNode.innerText.match(regXSearch);
      var totalMatches = 0;
      if (matches) {
        var totalChildElements = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<currentNode.children.length;i++) {
          if (!(currentNode.children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase().match(/html|script|head|meta|link|object/))) {
            totalChildElements++;
          }
        }
        matchedNodes.push({node: currentNode, numMatches: matches.length, childElementsWithMatch: 0, nodesYetTraversed: totalChildElements});
      }
      for (var i = matchedNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        previousElement = matchedNodes[i - 1];
        if (!previousElement) {
          continue;
        }
        if (previousElement.nodesYetTraversed !== 0 && previousElement.numMatches !== previousElement.childElementsWithMatch) {
          previousElement.childElementsWithMatch++;
          previousElement.nodesYetTraversed--;
        }      
        else if (previousElement.nodesYetTraversed !== 0) {
          previousElement.nodesYetTraversed--;
        }               
      }
    }
  }
  var processedMatches = [];
  for (var i =0; i <  matchedNodes.length; i++) {
    if (matchedNodes[i].numMatches > matchedNodes[i].childElementsWithMatch) {
      processedMatches.push(matchedNodes[i].node);
    }
  }
  return processedMatches; 
};
```