# RegEx question - HTML tag content

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all "i" character in `<body>` with "I" by JavaScript.
(for example: `<div id="123">Hi! it!</div>` should change to `<div id="123">HI! It!</div>`).
I know I must use regular expressions. but I don't know what I should write.
Can you help me?
Thanks ..

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: How do you know that you 'must' use regex?

Comment: Because I want to replace "i" with "I", only in contents and not in tags ...

Comment: If it's HTML/XML, don't use regular expressions. [Historic archives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) of Stackoverflow will tell you why.

Comment: @darioo: I begin to see you guys' point (and weariness).

Comment: Come on, people. Closing this as a duplicate is plain wrong. How is it even similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered a similar question which may help you: [JQuery/Javascript - Search DOM for text and insert HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489119/jquery-javascript-search-dom-for-text-and-insert-html/4489601#4489601)

For this particular case, you can simplify.

**UPDATE**

I've added a `filter` parameter to allow you to filter out descendants of particular nodes. This should be a function that takes a single DOM node parameter and returns a Boolean: `true` to replace text within the node and its descendants and `false` to ignore the node and its descendants.

```
function replaceText(node, regex, replacementText, filter) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(regex, replacementText);
    } else if (!filter || filter(node)) {
        var child = node.firstChild;
        while (child) {
            replaceText(child, regex, replacementText, filter);
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}

function scriptAndStyleFilter(node) {
    return node.nodeType != 1 || !/SCRIPT|STYLE/i.test(node.nodeName);
}

replaceText(document.body, /i/g, "I", scriptAndStyleFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks ... your function is great! but how can filter <script>, <style> tag? this means stop replacing in these tags content.

Comment: @kikio: What exactly is the problem with it? By the way, `<style>` elements are not valid within the `<body>` element of an HTML document (even though it does work in most browsers).

Comment: I wrote on that page: `<style type="...">#myid {font-family: tahoma}</style><span id="myid">Hi! it!</span>`
I want it changed to this: `<style type="...">#myid {font-family: tahoma}</style><span id="myid">HI! It!</span>` (all of <style> contents must don't be changed)

Comment: Right... and that's what happens.

Comment: (with your new code): `<style type="...">#myId {font-famIly: tahoma}</style><span id="myid">HI! It!</span>`

Comment: @kikio: Humble apologies, you're absolutely right. I've edited my answer to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks .. your new new code works perfectly! but another question, can I works with ASCII code of character instead

Comment: (I'm sorry, my previous comment is not complete. so I write it again:)  Thanks .. your new new code works perfectly! but another question, can I works with ASCII code of character instead of normal character mode? for example, use "73" instead of "I". or "106" instead of "i".

Comment: You could use Unicode escape seuqences. The following is equivalent to the last line of my answer: `replaceText(document.body, /\u0069/g, "\u0049", scriptAndStyleFilter);`. Or you could build strings using `String.fromCharCode()`. For example, `String.fromCharCode(102, 111, 111)` returns "foo".

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks!! Thank you very much! I know you're a big man in JavaScript! (unfortunately, I don't have many knowledge in JavaScript. Can you give me a code, with ASCII replacing (uses String.fromCharCode? I tried this code, but it only replaced first "i": `replaceText(document.body, String.fromCharCode(106), String.fromCharCode(102, 111, 111), scriptAndStyleFilter);` thank you very very very much.)

Comment: The second parameter was a regular expression literal, and you've replaced it with a string, which changes the functionality. However, there is also a `RegExp` constructor which takes a string pattern: `replaceText(document.body, new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(106), "g"), String.fromCharCode(102, 111, 111), scriptAndStyleFilter);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, using CSS, jQuery and a [Highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html):

CSS:

```
.highlight {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('body').highlight('i');
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/okavo4

This is a quick example, but you can use the source code to get what you want, in case you need something more complex. Using a regular expression on the source of your body is wrong, specially in context of a browser, where you already have a parsed DOM structure.

Comment: @kikio - I did just that, and in just a few minutes. The plugin allows you to exclude certain elements, if that is what you need. A regex here would be difficult or down right impossible.