# What is the best approach to search some text in body html

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

As of now I am using the JavaScript search method to replace some text in body HTML like below..

Suppose my html is

```
 <body>
      <div> I am in body...</div>
 </body>
```

Then I am using the below approach

```
 var body = $(body);
 var text = body.html();
 text = text.replace('I am in body...','Yes');
 body.html(text);
```

But I could see slow page search in browsers like IE..
Please suggest me to improve this and also please let know if there are any plugins to search and match a string even if it contains any html tags in it..  Like below

```
 <body>
       <div><span>I </span> am in body...</div>
 </body>
```

With the current method I cannot match this..
If i use

```
  $('*:contains("some search text string")');
```

This will match the DIV and BODY as well.. But here I want to search the html text not parent element...
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a look at :

**ranges:**(to modify text without overwriting the complete body)

IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range

---

**find()/findText()**(to create the ranges)

IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find

(Opera doesn't support find or findText)

---

Regarding to that **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489119/jquery-javascript-search-dom-for-text-and-insert-html/4489271#4489271)** a small modification:

```
<html>
<head>

  <script>
  function fx(a,b)
  {
    if(window.find)
    {
      while(window.find(a))
      {

        var rng=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        rng.deleteContents();

        rng.insertNode(document.createTextNode(b));

      }
    }
    else if(document.body.createTextRange)
    {
      var rng=document.body.createTextRange();
      while(rng.findText(a))
      {
        rng.pasteHTML(b);
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="fx('I am in body...','Yes')">
<div>Oh <span>I </span>am in body...<i>, wonderful</i></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @dr-molle Very very thanks... I am searching for this solution from a long.. You made my day

Comment: @dr-molle Could you please look into this... http://jsfiddle.net/3gPbh/ .. Please tell the mistake in my code..

Comment: You didn't pass the expected arguments, the call has to be `fx('I am in body...','Yes')`

Comment: @dr-molle Thanks for your response.. I have tried to search few words like I specified in fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

you will get only the elements that contain the full text
 without being a parent to some other element that contains the same text

```
var str = "some search text string";
var elements = $("*:contains('"+ str +"')").filter(
                  function(){
                      return $(this).find("*:contains('"+ str +"')").length == 0
                  }
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is work well, but your error is you didn't figure out the "body" content.

Here is your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body = $("body");    // your miss this
    var text = body.html();
    text = text.replace('I am in body...','Yes');
    body.html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('body:contains("some search text string")');
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I can use $('*:contains("some search text string")'); but I just want to search the string not the parent.. Also this will match the parent tag and also body tag..